# Search confuses periods and underscores

Tags: search

I'm debugging a problematic function that imports another function with a similar name - `read_table` vs `read.table`. I've examined the file in sublime, which concludes that there are no instances of `read.table`.

However, when I run `?read.table`, vim just iterates over all the instances of `read_table`. Is the period some sort of wildcard for vim search? How can I get around this problem to find the true instances of `read.table`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A period means "any character" in a regular expression. Use `\.`:

```
?read\.table
```

See `:help regexp` for more details. Specifically, see `:help /.`